# How to rotate and scale a Rectangle2D in java and return a Rectangle2D (not a Shape or Path2D)

Tags: java, transform, rectangles, java-2d

Is it possible to scale or rotate a Rectangle2D and get a new transformed Rectangle2D?
I know it is possible to get a Shape or Path2D, but how to get a new Rectangle2D from a specific Affine transform that in theory return a Rectangle also?

Maybe reconstruct a new Rectangle2D from Path2D (iteration?), but how?
Rectangle2D will feed the TexturePaint class anchor parameter.

methods that return a Path2D/Shape

```
       private Path2D.Double transformRotate(Rectangle2D.Double rect) {
    
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
          double theta=0.5;
        double angle = Math.toRadians(theta);
    //  transform.rotate(angle, rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2);   
        transform.rotate( orientationX, orientationY, rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2);
        
        return new Path2D.Double(rect, transform);
    }
```

```
                AffineTransform transformRect = new AffineTransform();
transformRect.rotate(orientationX, orientationY, rectFinal.getX() + rectFinal.getWidth()/2, rectFinal.getY() + rectFinal.getHeight()/2);

Shape rotatedRect =  transformRect.createTransformedShape(rectFinal); //or path2D
```

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986287/what-is-the-correct-way-to-convert-a-shape-to-a-rectangle2d-double - I would say, no, it's not possible

Comment: `Path2D` has a `getBounds2D` method which returns a `Rectangle2D`, but I'm not sure if this is what you really want

Comment: thanks for the replies. I have used getBounds2D, but it seems it only returns a bigger horizontally/vertically aligned rectangle, not a real rotated shape. Maybe I can manually try to recreate it by iterating through path2D points and calculate width & height.

Comment: Well, that's kind of the point of `Rectangle2D` it's a rectangle. Looking at `TexturePaint`, you're passing in a `BufferedImage` and the `Rectangle2D` represents the "user space used to anchor" the texture, so what you really want to be doing is rotating the image - having said that, the `createContext` method takes an `AffineTransform`, so maybe, you should be rotating applying the rotation to the `TexturePaint` instead ... never used it so I'm just guessing at a lot of the functionality

Comment: Why do you care so much bout getting width and height?

Comment: As MadProgrammer noted
 It looks like there is no such thing as rotation of Rectangle2D, because it is axis aligned, thanks, now it is clear. As for the createContext it can be done as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281815/java-custom-paint-implementation-performance-issue but then it is a new implementation of Paint interface